# How can I fix a nonconformant arguments error in Octave when I am not using an operator?

Tags: vector, runtime-error, octave

I am a bit new to octave and programming in general. I am trying to create a vector of Forces that apply to multiple bodies, but when I try to initialize the vector variable, octave returns an error when calculating `Fn1`:

```
menuTest: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 2x1)
```

I know that if you try to use an operator on two matrices that don't agree, it will return an error, however, that is not what I am trying to do here.

I have tried: changing the commas to semicolons and removing them completely.

I expect the terminal to output a vector array, but it produces an error.

```
function menuTest
    Xs = 0
    rs =0
    G = 6.67*10e-11
    S = 2e30
    dt = .1
    m = 6e20
    e = .0167
    b = a*sqrt(1-(e.^2))
    X(1) = a
    Y(1) = 0
    vX(1) = 10
    vY(1) = 0
    %P2
    a1 = a + 14e6
    X1(1) = a1
    Y1(1) = 0
    r(1) = sqrt(X(1).^2 + Y(1).^2)
    r1(1)  = sqrt(X1(1).^2 + Y1(1).^2)
    %Force on body 1
    F(1) = (S)*(G*m)/((rs(1)-r(1)).^2)
    F21(1) = (S)*(G*m)/((r1(1)-r(1)).^2)
    %Force on body 2
    F12(1) = (S)*(G*m)/((r(1)-r1(1)).^2)
    F1(1) = (S)*(G*m)/(r1(1).^2)`
    %Force vectorization initialization
    Fn1(1) = [F(1),F21(1)]
    unit(1) = [(Xs(1)-X(1)), (X1(1)-X(1))]
    unitFn1(1) = dot(Fn1,unit(1))
    Fn2(1) = [F1(1),F12(1)]
    unit1(1) = [(Xs(1)-X(1)),(X(1)-X1(1))]
    unitFn2(1) = dot(Fn2,unit1(1))
endfunction
```

I expect `Fn1` to output a vector with `F` and `F21` and it's elements. Instead, I am getting

```
error: menuTest: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x2)
```

Comment: Try to create a MCVE. In this case the "minimal" is important. For example, if you strip down your function and only leave `Xs=0` in the Funktion body, do you still see the same error? If yes, there is no reason to add so much unneeded code. Very offen you'll find the problem yourself if you have stripped the code to the bare minimum

Comment: what is `a` ? I suggest you to test the code one line at time to find the likely typo mistake in your formula. In general is not a good idea to redefine `e`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I got the error

`error: menuTest: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x2)
    error: called from
    menuTest at line 37 column 10`

when initializing:

```
`Fn(1) = [F(1),F21(1)]`
```

I removed the (1) and it worked. I got

`Fn1 =
     3.5573e+19   4.0837e+27`

at the terminal. I'm guessing you can't initialize or use an iterator in vectorization.

Comment: You were trying to store two values at a single memory location. `Fn(1:2)` would be it if you want to specify indices. And this has nothing to do with vectorization